# How do I combine results from two queries on the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to return exactly ten records for use in a view. I have a highly restrictive query I'd like to use, but I want a less restrictive query in place to fill in the results in case the first query doesn't yield ten results.

Just playing around for a few minutes, and this is what I came up with, but it doesn't work. I think it doesn't work because merge is meant for combining queries on different models, but I could be wrong.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def self.listed_articles
    Article.published.order('created_at DESC').limit(25).where('listed = ?', true)
  end

  def self.rescue_articles
    Article.published.order('created_at DESC').where('listed != ?', true).limit(10)
  end

  def self.current
    Article.rescue_articles.merge(Article.listed_articles).limit(10)
  end
...
end
```

Looking in console, this forces the restrictions in listed_articles on the query in rescue_articles, showing something like:

```
Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (published = 1) AND (listed = 1) AND (listed != 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 4
Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (published = 1) AND (listed = 1) AND (listed != 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 4
```

I'm sure there's some ridiculously easy method I'm missing in the documentation, but I haven't found it yet.

EDIT:
What I want to do is return all the articles where listed is true out of the twenty-five most recent articles. If that doesn't get me ten articles, I'd like to add enough articles from the most recent articles where listed is not true to get my full ten articles.

EDIT #2:
In other words, the merge method seems to string the queries together to make one long query instead of merging the results. I need the top ten results of the two queries (prioritizing listed articles), not one long query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with your initial code:

You can join two arrays using + then get first 10 results:

```
  def self.current
    (Article.listed_articles  +  Article.rescue_articles)[0..9]
  end
```

I suppose a really dirty way of doing it would be:

```
  def self.current
      oldest_accepted = Article.published.order('created_at DESC').limit(25).last
      Artcile.published.where(['created_at > ?', oldest_accepted.created_at]).order('listed DESC').limit(10)
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that would do. I'm going to edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: OK. This would essentially load all the published articles, with all the listed = true at top. Then ordered by created_at. Then limited to 10. So if only have 3 listed, it would return these 3 then 7 from non listed. If you had 12 listed, it would return first 10 listed

Comment: The reason I'm not doing that is because I don't want any articles included that are not in the twenty-five most recent, whether they're listed or not. I'd rather have unlisted articles filling out the ten results than articles older than the latest twenty-five.

Comment: That's still not what I need. Putting the limit(25) condition right there yields the first 25 in the table.

Comment: Now you're headed the right direction, except what if there are only 3 out of the last 25 articles that are listed? I need exactly 10 records. So if there aren't 10 listed articles in the 25 most recent articles, I need to supplement the listed articles with non-listed articles to get exactly 10.

Comment: The current method should essentially get the recent 25 articles and order these by listed (true first). It then limits this to 10. Does this not work?

Comment: It's so close, but it's still just stringing the queries together into one long statement:

"Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (published = 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC, listed DESC"

Comment: That makes the array, but then I can't manipulate it any more like a normal AR object (which does happen in a view).

Comment: Dirty hack works for now. I'll mark yours as the accepted answer for it, but I'm going to keep searching for a rails trick that lets me combine the results from two queries without simply merging the queries into a single statement.

Comment: Actually, the more I look at it, the more I realize the dirty hack is quite expressive of what I want to do. I'm just going to leave it alone. Thanks.

Comment: When I use this with will_paginate I get `undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x108497880>`

Answer (score 7):

If you want an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object instead of an Array, you can use:

- [ActiveRecordUnion gem](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union).

  Install gem: `gem install active_record_union` and use:

  ```
  def self.current
    Article.rescue_articles.union(Article.listed_articles).limit(10)
  end
  ```
- [UnionScope module](https://gist.github.com/lsiden/260167a4d3574a580d97).

  Create module UnionScope (lib/active_record/union_scope.rb).

  ```
  module ActiveRecord::UnionScope
    def self.included(base)
      base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def union_scope(*scopes)
        id_column = "#{table_name}.id"
         if (sub_query = scopes.reject { |sc| sc.count == 0 }.map { |s|   "(#{s.select(id_column).to_sql})" }.join(" UNION ")).present?
          where "#{id_column} IN (#{sub_query})"
        else
          none
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```

  Then call it in your Article model.

  ```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveRecord::UnionScope
    ...
    def self.current
      union_scope(Article.rescue_articles, Article.listed_articles).limit(10)
    end
    ...
  end
  ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19438865)

Comment: Thanks for your review @petezurich! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is sum the queries:

```
result1 = Model.where(condition)
result2 = Model.where(another_condition)

# your final result
result = result1 + result2
```

Comment: FYI:
This does not work with AR:AssociationRelations.

NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<Model::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007ff9e7aa1160>

Comment: This will combine/merge the final results fine. But it loses its active record properties. You cannot use further scopes on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do all of this in one query:

```
 Article.published.order('listed ASC, created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

I may have the sort order wrong on the listed column, but in essence this should work.  You'll get any listed items first, sorted by created_at DESC, then non-listed items.

Comment: That would prioritize listed articles older than the 25 most recent over newer unlisted articles, which isn't what I need.

Comment: I must be missing something. By putting the "listed ASC" first, it would sort the table with all of the null or 0 values in listed (unlisted) at the beginning of the result.  If there are 2 of them, they would be at the top, then you'd have the most recent items with a 1 in the listed column (aka listed items).

If this isn't the right understanding, perhaps you could edit the question with a couple of sample records to show what the result should look like.

Comment: The "listed ASC" puts a priority on the unlisted articles, which is the opposite of what I need.