# Need two return an activerecord relation from two queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this two queries on my database

```
incidents = Incident.arel_table

Incident.where(incidents[:client_id].in(client_ids_including_descendants(false)))

Incident.joins(:incident_support_requests)
        .where(incident_support_requests: { 
                 provider_type: 'SocProvider',                                                                                          
                 provider_id: self.soc_provider_ids,                                                                                       
                 state: 'opened'})
```

And I need to join in one `ActiveRecord::Relation`, without calculating intermediate queries (ie with a +) I followed the answers from here
[How do I combine results from two queries on the same model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411702/how-do-i-combine-results-from-two-queries-on-the-same-model)

when trying to join this two queries with should be an or the results from one plus the results form the other I always get couldn't visis active record relation
but I couldn't get it

Comment: If you are using `rails`  5.X then you can just use `or` and possibly `left_outer_join` (not sure about your relationships) such as `Incident.left_outer_joins(:incident_support_requests).where(#YOUR Search Hash).or(Incident.where(incidents[:client_id].in(client_ids_including_descendants(false))))` If not then I would suggest building the query in Arel or writing it in pure SQL

Comment: This is teh problem I'm using a really old rails version

Comment: Then my suggestion is use SQL e.g. `Incident.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN incident_support_requests ON incident_support_requests.incident_id = incidents.id").where("incidents.client_id IN (?) OR (incident_support_requests.provider_type = ? AND incident_support_requests.provider_id = ? AND incident_support_requests.state = ?)", client_ids_including_descendants(false), 'SocProvider', self.soc_provider_ids, 'opened')`

Comment: Ok I will try it

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
incid1 = ...
incid2 = ...

incids = Incident.where(id: incid1.pluck(&:id) + incid2.pluck(&:id))
```

Comment: The problemes with this is that returns anys atrau oficial ids, I need the actives record relation

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what "anys atrau oficial ids" is. But both queries are around the Incident model. I think you may need to post more code ex (what is self.soc_provider_ids or the file generating both queries)

Comment: That query returns an array of Ids. Not the  active record relation the query is shomwthing IN (id1 .... idn) on large numbers of ids this is a bad query

Comment: Yes you should reconsider the design and use scopes so you don't have to merge two different queries.

Comment: Well I need that query, and the comments in the question by @engineermnky seems to be the right query